# Net::SMTP - stopped working, but I'm not sure why [IO::Socket::SSL ?]

Tags: perl, ssl, smtp

I'm really baffled with this one! We have a system that emails out invoices to customers, and its worked fine - up until about a month ago. I've had a few people contacting me for an invoice, which I thought was a bit weird. Anyway, I took a look into the script, and it seems like its stopped sending! (it hangs at the `$smtp->data($email);` line)

This is the code:

```
my $to          = qq|"Andy" <andy.newby\@gmail.com>|;
my $subject_val = "test subject";

my $write_path = "/srv/www/mysite.net/www/cgi-bin/admin/invoice_pdfs/new/pdf_versions/$order->{amazon_order_id}.pdf";
my $file_name  = "$order->{amazon_order_id}.pdf";

if (!-e $write_path) {
    print qq|PDF doesn't seem to exist yet! SKIPPING ($write_path) \n|;
    next;
}

print "TO: $to \n";

my $to          = qq|"$order->{buyer_name}" <andy.newby\@gmail.com>|;
my $subject_val = sprintf($languages->{subject}->{$lang},$order->{amazon_order_id});

my $write_path = "/srv/www/mysite.net/www/cgi-bin/admin/invoice_pdfs/new/pdf_versions/$order->{amazon_order_id}.pdf";
my $file_name  = "$order->{amazon_order_id}.pdf";

my $msg = MIME::Lite->new(
    Type     => 'multipart/mixed',
    Subject  => $subject_val,
    To => $to,
    From => $from
);

# create a sub-part
my $part = MIME::Lite->new(
    Type => 'multipart/alternative',
);

my $att_html = MIME::Lite->new(
    Type     => 'text',
    Data     => "text version",
    Encoding => 'quoted-printable',
);
$att_html->attr('content-type' => 'text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1');
$part->attach($att_html);

my $att_text = MIME::Lite->new(
    Type     => 'text',
    Data     => "html version",
    Encoding => 'quoted-printable',
);
$att_text->attr('content-type' => 'text/html; charset=iso-8859-1');
$part->attach($att_text);

$msg->attach($part);

$msg->attach(
     Type     =>'application/pdf',
     Path     => $write_path,
     Filename => $file_name,
     Disposition => 'attachment'
);

my $email = $msg->as_string();

# now do the sending...
my $smtp = Net::SMTP->new('smtp.gmail.com',
                       Hello => 'steampunkjunkies.net',
                       Timeout => 30,
                       Debug   => 1,
                       SSL     => 1
                      ) || die "Error: $!";

$smtp->auth($CFG->{db_smtp_user}, $CFG->{db_smtp_pass}) or die "Could not authenticate with mail.\n";

$smtp->mail($from); # from addr
$smtp->to($to);
$smtp->bcc('myemail@gmail.com');
$smtp->data($email); # It hangs here
$smtp->quit();
```

After some debugging, I tracked it down to this code:

```
$msg->attach(
     Type     =>'application/pdf',
     Path     => $write_path,
     Filename => $file_name,
     Disposition => 'attachment'
);
```

If I comment that part out, it works fine (but obviously with no attachment!!!). Here is the debug from **Net::SMTP**:

```
Net::SMTP::_SSL>>> Net::SMTP::_SSL
Net::SMTP::_SSL>>>   IO::Socket::SSL(2.019)
Net::SMTP::_SSL>>>     IO::Socket::IP(0.32)
Net::SMTP::_SSL>>>       IO::Socket(1.38)
Net::SMTP::_SSL>>>         IO::Handle(1.35)
Net::SMTP::_SSL>>>           Exporter(5.71)
Net::SMTP::_SSL>>>   Net::SMTP(3.10)
Net::SMTP::_SSL>>>     Net::Cmd(3.10)
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x2d3b7a0)<<< 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP d64sm16899171wmh.3 - gsmtp
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x2d3b7a0)>>> EHLO steampunkjunkies.net
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x2d3b7a0)<<< 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [2a01:7e00::f03c:91ff:fea8:e2c5]
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x2d3b7a0)<<< 250-SIZE 35882577
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x2d3b7a0)<<< 250-8BITMIME
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x2d3b7a0)<<< 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x2d3b7a0)<<< 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x2d3b7a0)<<< 250-PIPELINING
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x2d3b7a0)<<< 250-CHUNKING
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x2d3b7a0)<<< 250 SMTPUTF8
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x2d3b7a0)>>> AUTH LOGIN
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x2d3b7a0)<<< 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x2d3b7a0)<<< (decoded) Username:
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x2d3b7a0)>>> (decoded) xxx@xxxx.xxx
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x2d3b7a0)>>> YWRtaW5Ac3RlYW1wdW5rLmVtYWls
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x2d3b7a0)<<< 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x2d3b7a0)<<< (decoded) Password:
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x2d3b7a0)>>> (decoded) xxxx
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x2d3b7a0)>>> xxxxx==
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x2d3b7a0)<<< 235 2.7.0 Accepted
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x2d3b7a0)>>> MAIL FROM:<andy@steampunkjunkies.net>
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x2d3b7a0)<<< 250 2.1.0 OK d64sm16899171wmh.3 - gsmtp
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x2d3b7a0)>>> RCPT TO:<andy.newby@gmail.com>
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x2d3b7a0)<<< 250 2.1.5 OK d64sm16899171wmh.3 - gsmtp
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x2d3b7a0)>>> RCPT TO:<andy.newby@gmail.com>
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x2d3b7a0)<<< 250 2.1.5 OK, duplicate recipients will be consolidated. d64sm16899171wmh.3 - gsmtp
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x2d3b7a0)>>> DATA
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x2d3b7a0)<<< 354  Go ahead d64sm16899171wmh.3 - gsmtp
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x2d3b7a0)>>> Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x2d3b7a0)>>> Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="_----------=_1480928361299110"
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x2d3b7a0)>>> MIME-Version: 1.0
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x2d3b7a0)>>> X-Mailer: MIME::Lite 3.030 (F2.85; T2.11; A2.13; B3.15; Q3.13)
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x2d3b7a0)>>> Date: Mon, 5 Dec 2016 08:59:21 +0000
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x2d3b7a0)>>> Subject: test subject
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x2d3b7a0)>>> To: "Andy" <andy.newby@gmail.com>
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x2d3b7a0)>>> From: Steampunk Junkies <andy@steampunkjunkies.net>
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x2d3b7a0)>>> 
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x2d3b7a0)>>> This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x2d3b7a0)>>> 
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x2d3b7a0)>>> --_----------=_1480928361299110
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x2d3b7a0)>>> Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x2d3b7a0)>>> Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="_----------=_1480928361299111"
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x2d3b7a0)>>> MIME-Version: 1.0
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x2d3b7a0)>>> X-Mailer: MIME::Lite 3.030 (F2.85; T2.11; A2.13; B3.15; Q3.13)
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x2d3b7a0)>>> Date: Mon, 5 Dec 2016 08:59:21 +0000
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x2d3b7a0)>>> 
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x2d3b7a0)>>> This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x2d3b7a0)>>> 
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x2d3b7a0)>>> --_----------=_1480928361299111
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x2d3b7a0)>>> Content-Disposition: inline
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x2d3b7a0)>>> Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x2d3b7a0)>>> Content-Type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x2d3b7a0)>>> MIME-Version: 1.0
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x2d3b7a0)>>> X-Mailer: MIME::Lite 3.030 (F2.85; T2.11; A2.13; B3.15; Q3.13)
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x2d3b7a0)>>> Date: Mon, 5 Dec 2016 08:59:21 +0000
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x2d3b7a0)>>> 
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x2d3b7a0)>>> plain text version
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x2d3b7a0)>>> 
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x2d3b7a0)>>> --_----------=_1480928361299111
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x2d3b7a0)>>> Content-Disposition: inline
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x2d3b7a0)>>> Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x2d3b7a0)>>> Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x2d3b7a0)>>> MIME-Version: 1.0
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x2d3b7a0)>>> X-Mailer: MIME::Lite 3.030 (F2.85; T2.11; A2.13; B3.15; Q3.13)
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x2d3b7a0)>>> Date: Mon, 5 Dec 2016 08:59:21 +0000
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x2d3b7a0)>>> 
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x2d3b7a0)>>> html version
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x2d3b7a0)>>> 
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x2d3b7a0)>>> --_----------=_1480928361299111--
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x2d3b7a0)>>> 
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x2d3b7a0)>>> 
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x2d3b7a0)>>> --_----------=_1480928361299110
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x2d3b7a0)>>> Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="205-2876651-1862762.pdf"
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x2d3b7a0)>>> Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x2d3b7a0)>>> Content-Type: application/pdf; name="205-2876651-1862762.pdf"
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x2d3b7a0)>>> 
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x2d3b7a0)>>> JVBERi0xLjMKMSAwIG9iago8PCAvVHlwZSAvQ2F0YWxvZwovT3V0bGluZXMg
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x2d3b7a0)>>> MiAwIFIKL1BhZ2VzIDMgMCBSID4+CmVuZG9iagoyIDAgb2JqCjw8IC9UeXBl
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x2d3b7a0)>>> IC9PdXRsaW5lcyAvQ291bnQgMCA+PgplbmRvYmoKMyAwIG9iago8PCAvVHlw
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x2d3b7a0)>>> ZSAvUGFnZXMKL0tpZHMgWzYgMCBSCjIzIDAgUgpdCi9Db3VudCAyCi9SZXNv
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x2d3b7a0)>>> dXJjZXMgPDwKL1Byb2NTZXQgNCAwIFIKL0ZvbnQgPDwgCi9GMSA4IDAgUgov
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x2d3b7a0)>>> RjIgMTUgMCBSCj4+Ci9YT2JqZWN0IDw8IAovSTEgMjIgMCBSCj4+Cj4+Ci9N
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x2d3b7a0)>>> ZWRpYUJveCBbMC4wMDAgMC4wMDAgNjEyLjAwMCA3OTIuMDAwXQogPj4KZW5k
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x2d3b7a0)>>> b2JqCjQgMCBvYmoKWy9QREYgL1RleHQgL0ltYWdlQyBdCmVuZG9iago1IDAg
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x2d3b7a0)>>> b2JqCjw8Ci9Qcm9kdWNlciAo/v8AZABvAG0AcABkAGYAIAA8AGUANABiADQA
...rest of base64
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x23e9340)>>> bmZvIDUgMCBSCj4+CnN0YXJ0eHJlZgoxNjA5MTk2CiUlRU9GCg==
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x23e9340)>>> 
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x23e9340)>>> --_----------=_148092924910810--
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x23e9340)>>> .
```

I've taken out the base64 stuff for the attachment, as that would be very long. The only thing I can think of, is that Net::SMTP got updated to a newer version - but I'm not sure when/how this could have been done, as I'm the sysadmin (and I didn't do it)

With the debugger, I get:

```
perl -d test.cgi

Loading DB routines from perl5db.pl version 1.44
Editor support available.

Enter h or 'h h' for help, or 'man perldebug' for more help.

Malformed UTF-8 character (unexpected non-continuation byte 0x63, immediately after start byte 0xe9) at test.cgi line 24.
 at test.cgi line 24.
"my" variable $to masks earlier declaration in same scope at test.cgi line 87.
 at test.cgi line 87.
"my" variable $subject_val masks earlier declaration in same scope at test.cgi line 88.
 at test.cgi line 88.
"my" variable $write_path masks earlier declaration in same scope at test.cgi line 90.
 at test.cgi line 90.
"my" variable $file_name masks earlier declaration in same scope at test.cgi line 91.
 at test.cgi line 91.
IO::Socket::SSL::CODE(0x29d3f50)(/usr/local/share/perl/5.20.2/IO/Socket/SSL.pm:192):
192:            INIT { init() }
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               DB<1> r
void context return from CODE(0x29d3f50)
main::(test.cgi:14):    $| = 1;
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               DB<1> r
Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8

Doing: 205-2876651-1862762
TO: Indrek PÃ¤ri
$VAR1 = 'Indrek PÃ¤ri';
TO: "Andy" <andy.newby@gmail.com>
r



^X^CIO::Socket::SSL::readline(/usr/local/share/perl/5.20.2/IO/Socket/SSL.pm:1171):
1171:           if ( ! defined $poke or $poke eq '' ) {
```

**UPDATE 2:**

So it seems to be this line that is hanging:

```
   DB<1> n
^CIO::Socket::SSL::readline(/usr/local/share/perl/5.20.2/IO/Socket/SSL.pm:1171):
1171:           if ( ! defined $poke or $poke eq '' ) {
```

Comment: How about checking the dates of the module files? And please change the markdown on the debug: each line should start with four spaces, like your Perl code, not *greater-than, space*. I can't do it easily as I'm on a tablet.

Comment: @Borodin  sorry, I've fixed that up to a `code` section instead of quote. The version of Net:SMTP is 3.10. Having a look at the .pm files last modified date, it comes up as 1st August. I'm wondering if thats not the issue, as it seems to have started from the 20th of November

Comment: @Borodin - oh actually, it looks like the MODULE was updated on the 1st Aug 2016. I assumed that was the write time to my server, but I think it must be the timestamp from the tar.gz when it was installed. I'm not sure how you downgrade a module to an older version to test

Comment: Your calls to `data` and `datasend` don't look right. I think those two should be just `$smtp->data($email)`. If you prefer `datasend` then you should call `dataend` afterwards, although the log file looks like the data is terminated properly. You should check the return values of those last few calls from `auth` onwards.

Comment: @Borodin - thanks. Still no joy though :( I now have: `  $smtp->mail($from); $smtp->to($to); $smtp->bcc('andy.newby@gmail.com'); $smtp->data($email);`. Same issue as before - it just hangs. If I comment out the `attach()` part, it sends fine (just without the attachment)

Comment: Oh it *hangs*? That's useful to know. Try adding a call to `$smtp->dataend` after your `datasend`. Find out where it's hanging and *check the return values*

Comment: @Borodin - yeah it hangs (I've left it for 5 minutes, and it still didn't go). Adding some debugging in, and it hangs at this point: `$smtp->data($email);`. Nothing runs after it (but the code before does)

Comment: Okay, change it back to how it was, with `data()` and then `datasend()` and add `dataend()`and see where that hangs.

Comment: @Borodin - so like this?  `$smtp->data(); $smtp->datasend($email); $smtp->dataend(); $smtp->quit();` ? If so, it still hangs at `$smtp->datasend($email);`

Comment: Interesting. You need to invoke the Perl debugger and step through to find *where* it's hanging. What is the module trying to do that never completes?

Comment: @Borodin - how do I do that? :) Also, just to confirm I have tested this on my dev server, and the exact same script works. So it *has* to be something to do with the update of Net::SMTP.

Comment: @Borodin - I have run it using -d in the command line, and it still hangs at that section. I've added the debug to the OP

Comment: Ah, well it's not trivial if you don't know already. Read [`perldoc perldebug`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldebug.html). But essentially you run the program from the command line and add the `-d` option. Then single-step through the program by pressing `n` until you hit a line that hangs. Then run it again the same way, and on the hanging line press `s` instead of `n` to step *into* that subroutine, and then carry on with `n` again. To find the next hang. You'll probably want to take notes. Eventually you'll hit a call to core perl, and you will have found why it is hanging.

Comment: @Borodin - still no closer :( I think I've pinned it down to `IO::Socket::SSL::readline(/usr/local/share/perl/5.20.2/IO/Socket/SSL.pm:1236):
1236:           my $poke = Net::SSLeay::peek($ssl,1);`  $! seems to be "Interrupted system call", but I can't find out what that message even means :/

Comment: That is *much* closer. Can you *step into* the `Net::SSLeay::peek($ssl, 1)` line? Here's your next lesson: you can set a *breakpoint* at a line number using `b`, for instance `b 42`. It will tell you off if the line is not "breakable", i.e. it's blank or a comment or a continuation line. The you can *continue* using `c`, which will run the program until it hits a breakpoint, or terminates or fails.

Comment: The line number refers to the current source file, but you can precede it with a file path, so you should try `b /path/to/IO/Socket/SSL.pm` followed by `c`, which will run until that line in the module. (You can get the file paths of all the loaded modules with `x %INC`.) Then try `s` to step *into* the `peek` call and see if you get any further.

Comment: Once you've got as far as you can, you should gather together all of your information and present it as a new question. That will get the details out of the comments and also put more eyes on the problem.

Comment: @Borodin - thanks for the tips. I must be doing something wrong :) All I seem to get, is a loop: https://jpst.it/Q4uv . I can't seem to get it to go into the `peek()` function, to see whats going on in there :/

Comment: You can't step into `Net::SSLeay:.peek` because this is C and not Perl code. It looks like that it is busy waiting for the server to send a line (the response from the server), i.e. it is waiting for the end of line marker. Given that the problems occurs only when you use an attachment it might be that the mail server employs some content scanner (antivirus or similar) which croaks on the attachment. Have a look at the server logs.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich - ahh ok - that makes sense. I'll give it a go at some point with just a plain text file (as simple as it gets). If that still has an issue, I'll talk to Google about it (its using Google Apps to send the mail)

Comment: @SteffenUllrich - I have reported this to google, and they are going to investigate. The tech I spoke to was quite baffled as to why its only when an attachment is added, that the issue occurs. Hopefully they can track the issue down

Comment: @Borodin - finally got it! I've put the answer down below. After all that, it was a QP issue (for some reason it didn't like a specific charachter, and locks up... not sure why!). Thanks for much for sticking with me on this, and helping me learn a few cool tricks for debugging as well.... so not a total loss! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh my goodness! I can't believe this is what it was.

Basically, the issue is that either `MIME::Lite` or `Net::SMTP` don't seem to **Quoted-Printed** encode the persons name! I just spent about an hour on the phone to Google support, and we finally managed to pin it down to the **ä** charachter in the recipients name. For some reason it works fine with stuff like áíó, but not ä (and probably some other characters).

Anyway, for anyone else who may come across this in the future - the fix is pretty simple:

```
use Encode; 
my $to = qq|"| . encode("MIME-Q", $order->{buyer_name}) . qq|" <me\@gmail.com>|;
```

This basically converts the name, such as Päri, into quoted values:

```
To: "=?UTF-8?Q?=20P=C3=A4ri?=" <me@gmail.com>
```

I can't believe this took so long to work out :( Also, still very odd that the modules locked up when it got that character (instead of giving an error, or just sending with a broken character)

Hopefully this will help someone else in the future!

Comment: Well done. It's nice to know that Google support will actually help you to that extent. Most companies just provide a token "support" service whose job it is to prove that it's not their fault. Please accept your own answer.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, he certainly went above and beyond what I was expecting.  I didn't realise I could mark my own answer as correct yet (normally you have to wait a couple of days, but maybe its OK due to the fact the thread is a few days old). Thanks again!

Comment: It's probably because you've reached 1,000 reputation.